# textImage2D load 1 component texture without copy

Tags: javascript, webgl, webgl2

I'm trying to create 2D texture from an `ArrayBuffer` containing an image with 1 component. And I would like to do it without copying it into a 4 components images.
I would to know if it's possible with both `webgl` and `webgl2` (have more hope with webgl2).

#### webgl 1

I tried this one

```
gl.texImage2D(gl.TEXTURE_2D, 0, gl.LUMINANCE, width, height, 0, gl.LUMINANCE, gl.UNSIGNED_BYTE, pixelData);
```

I tried with both `gl.LUMINANCE` ans `gl.LUMINANCE_ALPHA` as the docs says

> Each color component is a ...

as opposed of `gl.ALPHA` for example where it says :

> Discards the red, green and blue components and reads the alpha component

From that it seems clear that `gl.ALPHA` will expect a 4 component image while `gl.LUMINANCE` and `gl.LUMINANCE_ALPHA` will only expect 1 component.
But when I do the following I get an error telling me the buffer is too small. If I pass in a buffer with 4 times the size there is no error so it seems it's also expecting a 4 component image after all.

I also tried with a width and height divided by 4 thinking I could outsmart the texture coord on my shader but came to the conclusion this was probably a bad idea for interpolation, or I would had to do it myself.

#### webgl 2

So I didn't had much expectation with webgl 1 but I was pretty sure this would be easy with webgl2. But unfortunately the following didn't work :

```
gl.texImage2D(gl.TEXTURE_2D, 0, gl.R8, this.image.width, this.image.height, 0, gl.RED, gl.UNSIGNED_BYTE, pixelData);
```

It's doing the exact same complain about buffer being to small and not throwing any error with a buffer 4 times bigger.

So is it possible with any (or both) version or am I doomed creating a temporary image with 4 components ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What kind of doc are you reading? None of the quotes you provided are true for `ArrayBuffers` and none of them can be found in the WebGL(1) specification.
`ALPHA` and `LUMINANCE` are both single channel formats only expecting a single value per pixel, the only effective difference between them is through what components you're able to access them in the shader. `LUMINANCE_ALHPA` however is a **two** channel format(first channel is mapped to `rgb` and second to `a`).

Now to your actual question, both WebGL 1 and 2 allow for single component data submission through `texImage2D`, however both are defaulting to an `UNPACK_ALIGNMENT` of 4(bytes).

> Specifies the alignment requirements for the start of each pixel row in memory. The allowable values are 1 (byte-alignment), 2 (rows aligned to even-numbered bytes), 4 (word-alignment), and 8 (rows start on double-word boundaries).

*[OpenGL ES 3.0 Manpage](https://www.khronos.org/registry/OpenGL-Refpages/es3.0/html/glPixelStorei.xhtml)*

Setting the `UNPACK_ALIGNMENT` to 1(byte) via the `pixelStorei` method resolves the issue.

```
ctx.pixelStorei(ctx.UNPACK_ALIGNMENT,1);
```

Attention though: this is a **global** setting(not bound to the active texture) and may lead to a performance penalty for texture data that could be unpacked with a better alignment. So you should determine the optimal unpack alignment on a per texture case(considering the format and data type) and set the alignment accordingly.

```js
var ctx=canvas.getContext('webgl');
// Create alpha texture
var tex = ctx.createTexture();
ctx.bindTexture(ctx.TEXTURE_2D, tex);
ctx.pixelStorei(ctx.UNPACK_ALIGNMENT,1);
ctx.texImage2D(ctx.TEXTURE_2D,0,ctx.ALPHA,2,2,0,ctx.ALPHA,ctx.UNSIGNED_BYTE,new Uint8Array([0,128,128,0]));
ctx.texParameteri(ctx.TEXTURE_2D,ctx.TEXTURE_MIN_FILTER,ctx.NEAREST);
ctx.texParameteri(ctx.TEXTURE_2D,ctx.TEXTURE_MAG_FILTER,ctx.NEAREST);

// Create screenspace shader program
var
  vshader=ctx.createShader(ctx.VERTEX_SHADER),
  fshader=ctx.createShader(ctx.FRAGMENT_SHADER),
  program=ctx.createProgram()
;
ctx.shaderSource(vshader,`
  attribute vec2 vPosition;
  void main() {
    gl_Position=vec4(vPosition,0,1);
  }
`);
ctx.compileShader(vshader);
ctx.attachShader(program,vshader);
ctx.shaderSource(fshader,`
  precision mediump float;
  uniform sampler2D tex;
  void main(){
    gl_FragColor=vec4(texture2D(tex,gl_FragCoord.xy*.05));
  }
`);
ctx.compileShader(fshader);
ctx.attachShader(program,fshader);
ctx.linkProgram(program);

// Create and bind screenspace geometry
ctx.bindBuffer(ctx.ARRAY_BUFFER, ctx.createBuffer());
ctx.bufferData(ctx.ARRAY_BUFFER, new Float32Array([
  -1,1, 1,1, 1,-1, -1,-1,
  -1,1, -1,-1, 1,-1, 1,1
]), ctx.STATIC_DRAW);
ctx.enableVertexAttribArray(0);
ctx.vertexAttribPointer(0,2,ctx.FLOAT,false,0,0);

// Render
ctx.useProgram(program);
ctx.drawArrays(ctx.TRIANGLE_FAN,0,4);
```

```css
canvas {outline:1px solid red;position:absolute;left:50%;transform:translateX(-50%);}
html{background:#aaa;}
```

```html
<canvas id="canvas"></canvas>
```

Comment: I was reffering [mdn](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/API/WebGLRenderingContext/texImage2D) not the official spec indeed.  
Since js is single threaded can't we change the `UNPACK_ALIGNMENT` for each texture ? Or could this creates trouble because texture creation are done in parallel by the GPU ?

Comment: Yes you can, and you should.

Comment: can you explain why `gl.texImage2D(gl.TEXTURE_2D, 0, gl.LUMINANCE_ALPHA, 1, 1, 0, gl.LUMINANCE_ALPHA, gl.UNSIGNED_BYTE, new Uint8Array([1, 30]) );` is giving me a color of `8, 8, 8, 30` ? Shouldn't the rgb value be the value of the first byte (1) ?

Comment: Yes it should but its hard to tell whats going on without knowing the context and how you're reading back the data. Maybe create another question.

Comment: ok did it https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45014858/how-does-gl-luminance-alpha-works